# Noun Phrase, Preposition Modifier

Tags: meaning, prepositions, usage

The subject of this thread was pre-discussed in another thread.  But the original question in that thread was poorly worded, so I had to start a new thread.
My question has to do with a mysterious class of noun phrases formed by appending a prepositional post modifier to a main noun, like:

> [main noun] [prepositional modifier]

Examples include:

> an obligation ***to*** his friends
>   a commitment ***to*** excellence
>   a key ***to*** the front door
>   an answer ***to*** that question
>   an assistant ***to*** the manager

From these noun phrases complete sentences could be formed by inserting a proper form of "be" between the main noun and preposition modifier, with or without a slight modification of the main noun by replacing the indefinite particle with a definite particle, demonstrative, or possessive:

> His obligation ***is to*** his friends.
>   His commitment ***is to*** excellence.
>   The key ***is to*** the front door.
>   This answer ***is to*** that question.
>   This assistant ***is to*** the manager.

For some reason, some of the above  complete sentences are not good English according to some native speakers.  Why is that?

Comment: I think you've got the right basic idea, but the verbs could use a little tweaking in a few cases, especially the last one, where "assistant" as a job title doesn't strongly imply a relationship to one who receives assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Your final examples are generally fine, but they are contextual. They require a specific situation for them to sound natural or make sense. The "X is to Y" structure is an uncommon form, usually used for contrast or for emphasis. So:

> His obligation is to his friends

is fine, if you're discussing what he's going to do or how he considers his responsibilities: "Will he stop looking for his friend's lost wallet? Or will he go chat up that woman? He won't stop looking; his obligation is to his friends."

Or

> This answer is to that question.

That makes sense, as a response to a previous comment like "I don't understand why this answer doesn't seem to relate to Question 4..." "Oh, well this answer is to that question" (along with a gesture indicating Question 5).

Without context, this kind of emphasis is unexpected and confusing. It's not ungrammatical; it's just semantically unclear. (Although there might be a more natural way to say most of what these sentences would communicate.)

The only sentence I have a real problem with is "This assistant is to the manager"--it seems very unlikely to me that you can find a context in which you would have to stress that this person only assists the manager, while others assist other people; and it's also just kind of weird to talk about people like interchangeable objects.

Comment: So whether the "X is to Y" structure is acceptable is just a matter of guessing?

Comment: It's not guessing (though it might seem like it if you're learning in a vacuum). It's about whether what you are saying makes sense in the situation. The structure will be most acceptable if you are correcting a confusion or emphasizing one choice over another. It's not a commonly used structure, and the usual rule applies: when in doubt, look for native-speaker example uses if you really want to understand it.